# How to connect dots in ordinary plot based on subject number

Tags: r

I am very afraid that I have been trying to invent the hot water, but I would like to connect the dots in the graphs below based on the subject number. In this case the subjects are rats, they are devided in three treatment groups and their weight is measured three times.

Is there a way I can easily connect the dots based on the rat its number?

The data looks like this (first 20 lines):

```
   Rat Group Measurement Weight
1    1     1          M0     57
2    2     1          M0     60
3    3     1          M0     52
4    4     1          M0     49
5    5     1          M0     56
6    6     1          M0     46
7    7     1          M0     51
8    8     1          M0     63
9    9     1          M0     49
10  10     1          M0     57
11  11     2          M0     61
12  12     2          M0     59
13  13     2          M0     53
14  14     2          M0     59
15  15     2          M0     51
16  16     2          M0     51
17  17     2          M0     56
18  18     2          M0     58
19  19     2          M0     46
20  20     2          M0     53
```

And the graph I am talking about is this one:

[image]

Which I am making with this code:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(data=data_long[data_long$Group==1,], Weight ~ as.numeric(Measurement), 
     ylim=c(0,200), pch=20, xlab="Measurement", main="Treatment group 1")
par(new=TRUE)
grid()
plot(data=data_long[data_long$Group==2,], Weight ~ as.numeric(Measurement), 
     ylim=c(0,200), pch=20, xlab="Measurement", main="Treatment group 2")
grid()
plot(data=data_long[data_long$Group==3,], Weight ~ as.numeric(Measurement), 
     ylim=c(0,200), pch=20, xlab="Measurement", main="Treatment group 3")
grid()
```

How do I ask R to connect the dots based on the rat number?

Thank you!

Edit: requested dput:

```
structure(list(Rat = 1:20, Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), Measurement = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("M0", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4"), class = "factor"), 
    Weight = c(57L, 60L, 52L, 49L, 56L, 46L, 51L, 63L, 49L, 57L, 
    61L, 59L, 53L, 59L, 51L, 51L, 56L, 58L, 46L, 53L)), .Names = c("Rat", 
"Group", "Measurement", "Weight"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you supply your data as `dput(head(data_long, 20))` as an edit to your post?

Comment: Reshape your data and use `matlines`.

Comment: So you want to connect all dots belonging to `data$rat==j` ? Then select the subsets of your current `x` and `y` data by rat number.  That's basically what Roland is suggesting.

Comment: Alternatively, use `ggplot` add a `geom_line()` and `group` by subject

Comment: If I select current x and y based on rat number, do you suggest that I use a loop to plot all the lines and each time select a rat?

Comment: Check the examples [**here**](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_%28ggplot2%29/#line-graphs_1) on how to use the `group` argument (by e.g. rat) in `geom_line`.

Comment: This will be challenging to do base graphics. Well, not challenging, but it will require some nested loops or `lapply` calls. Basically, instead of calling `plot` on your data, call empty plots in each panel (i.e., `plot(NA, xlim=c(1,5), ylim=c(0,200))`), and then use `lines` calls for each rat to draw the connected points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using `ggplot2`, since it can get tedious in base graphics

```
# sample dataset
set.seed(12345)
data <- data.frame(
  rat = factor(rep(1:5, times=6)),
  group = factor(rep(1:2, each=15)),
  measurement = factor(rep(1:3, each=5, times=2)),
  weight = runif(30, min=20, max=60))

# require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=measurement, y=weight, col=group, group=group:rat)) + 
geom_point() + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~group, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by everybody, you should use ggplot, or in case you use the base graphics, use some for loops. As I don't know ggplot yet, I used the for loops with this as a result.

It is still way easier than the struggle our professor had to go trough with SAS, so I don't mind the for loops...

Below is the code. Thanks everybody for your help.

[image]

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
lapply(1:3, function(g) {
    plot(data=data_long[data_long$Group==g,], Weight ~ as.numeric(Measurement), 
         ylim=c(0,200), pch=20, xlab="Measurement",
         main=paste("Treatment group",g))
    for(j in 1:max(data_long$Rat)){
      if(data_long[j,]$Group==g){
          lines(data_long[data_long$Rat==j,]$Measurement, 
                data_long[data_long$Rat==j,]$Weight)
      }
    }
    grid()
})
plot(data=data_long[data_long$Group==1,], Weight ~ Measurement, 
     ylim=c(0,200), pch=20, xlab="Measurement", main="Treatment group 1")
grid()
plot(data=data_long[data_long$Group==2,], Weight ~ Measurement, 
     ylim=c(0,200), pch=20, xlab="Measurement", main="Treatment group 2")
grid()
plot(data=data_long[data_long$Group==3,], Weight ~ Measurement, 
     ylim=c(0,200), pch=20, xlab="Measurement", main="Treatment group 3")
grid()
```

Comment: I'm going to post a simplification of your code. Make sure it still works. Revert my edit if it doesn't.

Comment: @Thomas, there seems to be a problem with this method.